# Calling a Method from button click

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java and I'm trying to run a method once a button is clicked and I am unsure if I'm on the right track. I am selecting 10 questions from a Sqlite database and would like to cycle through each question 0-9 everytime the button is clicked. Once all 10 questions are asked I will move to another activity. I have the app displaying the first question fine but I am having trouble calling the showQuestions method and increasing the questionNum int by one when the button is clicked and passing this onto the method. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the showQuestions method which I am trying to call.

```
public void showQuestions(Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(questionNum);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // Collect String Values from Query
        StringBuilder questiontxt = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder answertxt1 = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder answertxt2 = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder answertxt3 = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder answertxt4 = new StringBuilder("");
        String question = cursor.getString(2);
        String answer = cursor.getString(3);
        String option1 = cursor.getString(4);
        String option2 = cursor.getString(5);
        String option3 = cursor.getString(6);
        questiontxt.append(question).append("");
        answertxt1.append(answer).append("");
        answertxt2.append(option1).append("");
        answertxt3.append(option2).append("");
        answertxt4.append(option3).append("");
    }
}
```

This is the code for the button which I am working on. There are 4 buttons.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.option1_button:
        if (questionNum<9) {
            questionNum ++;
        }
        Questions.this.showQuestions(null);
        break;
    }
```

And this is the XML code for the buttons.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/option1_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/option3_button"/>
```

OnClick Listener for the button

```
View option1_button = findViewById(R.id.option1_button);
option1_button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Database Query and Allocation to Cursor

```
//Get the questions and allocate them to the Cursor
public Cursor getQuestions() {
//Select Query 
String loadQuestions = "SELECT * FROM questionlist ORDER BY QID LIMIT 10";
SQLiteDatabase db = questions.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(loadQuestions, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);
return cursor;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but I am having trouble calling the showQuestions method` - this is very vague, what are the symptoms? is it crashing? does it do anything? did `showQuestions` run? how do you know?

Comment: Hey Bert the first question is displayed fine but it crashes on the button click. So this looks to me that showQuestions runs through the first time it is called but does not when I try to call it from the button click. Thx

Comment: I am running the code without the intent lines at the moment will edit my main post to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Questions.this.showQuestions(null);
```

Why you pass null to the showQuestions method?

Let me guess - it crashes with `NullPointerException`.

Did you tried 
`showQuestions(getQuestions())`

EDIT:
Some general suggestions:

- don't load the question every time when the button is clicked.
- make some `Question` class containing all needed information for a question
- when `onCreate` is invoked, open the database and load all needed questions in some `Collection`, like `ArrayList<Question>`
- Every time when the user clicks a button, get the next `Question` element from the `Collection` and show it

Comment: Thanks fiction I do have an onClick listener in my code. I have tested my buttons with Intent and they appear to be working fine.

Comment: Not sure I tried to put the cursor and questionNum in there but recieved errors. Could this be my problem?

Comment: Null cursor is the main reason your current code is crashing, perhaps you can show the code where you create the cursor to the Database.

Comment: Hi fiction looks good I removed the code cursor.moveToPosition(questionNum); from showQuestions and the references to questionNum in the button setup and it is running now even though it is repeating only the first question over and over it is much closer then I was before. So thanks big time for your advice :-)

Comment: Fantastic thanks fiction I will follow your advice thanks again